setuptools local packaging with data files and single module
Project has the following directory structure
LUTs/
├── pyproject.toml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── src/
│   ├── init__.py
|   ├── CountyFIPS.csv
|   ├── SCCountyFIPS.pkl
│   └── NationwideCountyFIPS.pkl

where __init__.py is
import pickle
from bidict import bidict
# import APIEndpoint

with open(file='LUTs/src/SCCountyFIPS.pkl', mode='rb') as sc:
    sccounties = pickle.load(sc)

with open(file='LUTs/src/NationwideCountyFIPS.pkl', mode='rb') as us:
    uscounties = pickle.load(us)

SC_COUNTIES = bidict(sccounties)

US_FIPS = bidict(uscounties)

I'm using setuptools with setuptools.build_meta backend.
pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "LUTs"
description = "Lookup table utility; CRM tables, FIPS codes, etc."
version = "0.9"
dependencies = [
    "bidict"
]

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
src = ["*.csv", "*.pkl"]

MANIFEST.in
include src/*.pkl
include src/*.csv

This will be an internal-only package.  I'm not sure if this should be a namespace package, I've just read that I have to structure the .toml differently.  I don't have a setup.py or a setup.cfg, as the setuptools documentation states

To avoid executing arbitrary scripts and boilerplate code, we are transitioning from defining all your package information by running setup() to doing this declaratively - by using pyproject.toml (or older setup.cfg).


To ease the challenges of transitioning, we provide a quick guide to understanding how pyproject.toml is parsed by setuptools. (Alternatively, here is the guide for setup.cfg).

Running
python -m build
cding into dist/
pip install --force-reinstall LUTs-0.9-py3-none-any.whl or pip install --force-reinstall luts-0.9.tar.gz
produces LUTS-0.9.dist.info/ with
├── direct_url.json
├── INSTALLER
├── METADATA
├── RECORD
├── REQUESTED
├── top_level.txt
├── WHEEL

but no main .py file.  It installs in the same folder as pip -V, but still results in a ModuleNotFoundError. I only have one Python env on 3.12.6.

Take a look at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/, I think you need a directory with the name of your module under src. I suspect find isn't finding anything.

Probably if you rename the directory src to LUTs (i.e. flat layout) and remove both the [tool.setuptools.packages.find] and [tool.setuptools.package-data] sections from the pyproject.toml file, setuptools will do the right thing by default here.

Modifying the directory tree to
LUTs
├── pyproject.toml
├── MANIFEST.in
└── LUTs
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── CountyFIPS.csv
    ├── SCCountyFIPS.pkl
    └── NationwideCountyFIPS.pkl

and MANIFEST.in to
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "LUTs"
description = "Lookup table utility; CRM tables, FIPS codes, etc."
version = "0.9"
dependencies = [
    "bidict"
]

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["*"]

seems to work.

You should be able to accept your own answer.

In your answer, is that an example of the MANIFEST.in or the pyproject.toml file?
